# Grails 2.0: Disable All Logging for Resources

Tags: grails, log4j

Is it possible and how can I disable all logging for Resources?  For example:

> Error 2012-04-26 19:48:00,929 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR
>   resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing
>   /bundle-bundle_core_head.css, /css/main.css,
>   /lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css, a resource was required but not
>   found: /images/go-dn-on.gif

I'm glad I have it so I can fix it, but I really want to stop it from showing up in log files, although I still need to show ERROR level from everything else.

Comment: Hi, Did you get any working workaround for this? I also want to disable all the logging messages from resource plugin in my logging files.

Answer (score 1):

In Config.groovy log4j section add line

```
off 'org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceMeta'
```

Try the following for disable all logs

```
off 'grails.app.services.org.grails.plugin.resource',
'grails.app.taglib.org.grails.plugin.resource',
'grails.app.resourceMappers.org.grails.plugin.resource'
```

Answer (score 0):

In *appenders* section of *Config.groovy* add following appender:

```
    'null' name: 'empty'
```

Then, in log4j section redirect error messages from resource to this appender:

```
error empty: ['grails.app.services.org.grails.plugin.resource',
    'grails.app.taglib.org.grails.plugin.resource',      
    'grails.app.resourceMappers.org.grails.plugin.resource']
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  I'm still getting the ERROR logging for resource.ResourceMeta